# python - Object detection in images

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have several images in which there is always one, and only one, object "X".

Let's suppose to have a camera on an assembly line that takes a picture every time an object passes on the conveyor.

This object is usually in the centre of the image with small translations / rotations with respect to the nominal position.

I need to extract the coordinate of this object (classic bounding box with four edges), what is the best way to do it? Do I need some kind of NN or can I rely on something simpler like Jaccard similarity? Caveat, the object may have dirt on it, different colors, light reflection and eventually partialy covered (till 50%)

Does this kind of problem have a specific name? So I can google for some literature. I think it is different from standard obj-detection, since here I already know that there is the object that I'm looking for

Comment: "object". quite vague. perhaps just show some data.

Comment: I'm working as an external consultant and my client asked me not to share this information. Anyway I don't think it's relevant, like it isn't in object detection with NN.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this kind of problem have a specific name?

Yes. It is called "object detection".

No, your task is not different from "standard" object detection. I conclude that based on all the information you've provided.

You *don't* know that there is an object within view. There may be none in view, or multiple. Even if these objects are exactly spaced on a conveyor belt that passes the camera, this will be the case. At times, one object may be almost out of view, or not all that much.

Even if some sensor tells you to "look now, exactly one object is right there", the task is still to locate it.

That is "object detection".

> I need to extract the coordinate of this object (classic bounding box with four edges)

There is nothing to "extract" from an object detection task. Bounding boxes are *the expected output* of any object detection task.

> Do I need some kind of NN or [...]

> the object may have dirt on it, different colors, light reflection and eventually partialy covered

Given the information about your "object", the only possible recommendation would be to use AI. The strongest you can get. Because there's no telling how hard to detect your "object" is. You may claim that it's easy to detect but one would have to take your word for it.

Since you (or your consulting client) already determined that this must be solved **visually**, I will not go into alternatives.

Comment: ---You don't know that there is an object within view. There may be none in view, or multiple--- I said there is always 1 object. I understand your point, but it doesn't fit my case. The object is handled by a 6-axis robot, not a classical conveyor where things can pile up. Anyway thank you for you answer.

Comment: you said "every time an object passes on the conveyor", so I took that to mean there's a conveyor. I don't believe I implied that things might pile up, only that they pass into and out of the camera's view. you said nothing about a robot. please don't move the goalposts. your question is vague as it is. please review [ask]. vague questions are hard or impossible to answer, hence off-topic.

Comment: I wrote "let's suppose ... conveyor" and in another statement I wrote "1 and only 1 obj" w/o any "suppose" in front of it. So far you have "supposed" that 1) 0 or 2+ objs are possible (WRONG, and if not, it doesn't matter, requirements are clear) 2) a robot and a conveyor cannot coexist 3) maybe my client is dumb 4) I deceived him and I'm getting money. And the actual contribution? 0. Someone below less aggressive than you has been more helpful.

Comment: BTW, conveyor/robot doesn't change a iota in my question, but since you are so pedant on this detail, a robot put the obj on the conveyor, this one moves on and then the camera takes the pic. Hence you cannot have 0 / 2+ obj. Period. Does it change the question? No, 1 object in the image is the starting point, moved by a conveyor, handled by a robot, suddendly materialized, fell from the ceiling, 1 object. Indeed, again, someone below answered in a more helpful manner.